# Get contacts after picking from the UI

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, contacts

I need to add something to my xml layout so when the user clicks it , there is a kind of UI for contact selection (capable of selecting multiple contacts). I dont care in what type of data they are sent (I will convert them to a list). Please show me how it's done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will move you to your Contacts and you will be able to pick a number.

```
         Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,  Contacts.CONTENT_URI);

    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
```

Then you need to call OnActivityResult method and you  RequestCode will be PICK_CONTACT, and then you can do with this whatever you want.

Comment: let me test it and tell you

Comment: Definately orientated me